# Calculating areas by overlay analysis of two tables with several information

Tags: sql, mapinfo, overlay

I have to calculate the areas (m2) of the blue, green and yellow polygons within different vegetationtypes (also polygons - the table is overlaying the colormap). I have to calculate how large areas of the blue, green etc. polygons are within the different black symbols.

Can I calculate this in one SQL for all the color polygons?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not 100% clear whether both of your tables consist of vector polygons; this answer assumes that they do.

Let's say your tables are called `Colour` and `VegType` and they both have a field called `Name`. To get the overlapping areas for each combination of VegType to Colour you can use the following SQL:

`SELECT VegType.Name, Colour.Name, Sum(Area(Overlap(Colour.obj, VegType.obj), "sq m")) "Area_sqm"
    FROM Colour, VegType 
    WHERE Colour.obj INTERSECTS VegType.obj 
    GROUP BY VegType.Name, Colour.Name
    INTO Overlap`

This should give you results similar to:

`VegType.Name | Colour.Name | Area_sqm
     Tree     |    Green    |  50.3
     Tree     |    Yellow   |  25.8
     Tree     |    Blue     |  18.6
     Tree     |    Cyan     |  36.5
     Grass    |    Green    |  42.2
     Grass    |    Yellow   |  21.3
     Grass    |    Blue     |  62.2
     Grass    |    Cyan     |  12.4`

Comment: Great thanks!  Both tables are vector polygons - so it works!